# Returning values in lua

Tags: lua

```
function SearchDatabase(ply, value)
    local id = ply:SteamID()
    if id == nil then return end
    local query = ECLIPSEUSERDATA:query("SELECT " .. value .. " FROM main WHERE usersteamid = '" .. id .. "';")
    if not query then return end
    query.onData = function(q, d)
        if(#query:getData() >= 1)then
            print("[SQL]" .. value .. " = " .. tostring(d[value]))
            print(tostring(d[value]))
            return tostring(d[value])
        end
    end
    query.onError = function(db, err)
        print("[SQL] Failed to search database - Error: ", err)
    end
    query:start()
    query:wait()
end
```

```
function UpdatePlaytime(ply)
    if ply == nil then
        return
    end
    local PlayersPlaytime = SearchDatabase(ply, "playtime")
    print(PlayersPlaytime)
    local PlaytimeUpdate = PlayersPlaytime + 1
end
```

The problem i'm currently having is when the value: d[value], is returned to my function UpdatePlaytime() function it is returning a nil value and I have no idea how to fix it.

Console logs:

```
[SQL]playtime = 0
0
nil
```

Any help will appreciated thanks!

-D12

Comment: You're not returning a value to from `SearchDatabase`. you are returning the `d[value]` from an anonymous function to `SearchDatabase`  which then does not return any data to `UpdatePlaytime`.

Comment: @Nifim any ideas on how to fix this then?

Comment: what is the lua sql library you are using?

Comment: @Nifim mysqloo9

Comment: after a quick look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/FredyH/MySQLOO) I don't imidiately see a mechanisms to return data from `query.onData` but you could try referencing an upvalue that is in `SearchDatabase` from your anonymous function. something like `result` then you set `result = d[value]` in your anonymous and then return `result` from `SearchDatabase`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/g0CsJQE In the link, I had done that but it still doesn't fix the issue. @Nifim

Comment: i meant to return `ReturnValue` on line 69. and you should define `ReturnValue` as a local on line 52. and then just do `ReturnValue = d[value]` on line 60 and return nothing from the anonymous function